# RemoteObject in BlazeDS environment: Serializing objects from JAXB/XJC-generated classes

Tags: java, flash, serialization, marshalling, blazeds

I'm developing a webapp with Java backend and Flash (pure ActionScript) frontend using BlazeDS.

I'm using the [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html) stuff to send objects, using custom serialization, where I need to implement Externalizable (Java) and IExternalizable (AS) interfaces. This works fine so far.

But now I need to send objects from Java to Flash, whose classes are generated with [JAXB/XJC](http://jaxb.java.net/). Of course these generated Java classes don't implement the Externalizable interface, so it seems that I can't use my approach here.

One possibility seems to be writing a XJC plugin which makes the classes implement Externalizable. But this looks like a tough job...

Does anyone have a good idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The JAXB [Inheritance Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin) makes the generated classes "implement" interfaces by just adding "implement NameOfInterface" to the class definition. For the necessary methods to be implemented, another plugin needs to be developed.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to develop a JAXB plugin for this. That doesn't seem to be as nasty as I thought before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally developed a JAXB/XJC plugin. (If someone's interested, just contact me.)
Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- build a set of objects on top of your JAXB generated classes. I would choose this option.
- build a proxy on top of your JAXB generated classes which will serialize/deserialize accordingly each object. If your objects are implementing the Externalizable interface you can use the Dynamic Proxy API from Java, no need for dynamic code generation
- modify the blazeds distribution. I would stay away from it, but it is doable.

Comment: Wouldn't your first suggestion mean to sort of implement the classes generated with JAXB again? And actually I' dont't really understand the difference between your first and second suggestion.